# Is it possible to achieve class type inference?

Tags: scala, type-conversion, traits

Consider following code (which not compilable):

```
trait Entity {
    type T <: Reality
    def liveIn: Option[Class[_ <: Unit#T]]
}

abstract class World extends Entity {
    def liveIn = None
}
class Universe extends World { type T = Real.type }
class ParallelUniverse extends World { type T = Unreal.type }

abstract class Humanoid {
    def liveIn = Some(classOf[World#T])
}
class Human extends Humanoid { type T = Real.type }
class Alien extends Humanoid { type T = Unreal.type }

sealed trait Reality
case object Real extends Reality
case object Unreal extends Reality
```

Is it possible to infer or somehow implicitly place concrete class instance at Some(classOf[???])?

Comment: You mean `def liveIn: Option[World#T]`?

Comment: Yes, but mostly implementation at Humanoid class.

Comment: Can you clarify, what `def liveIn: Option[Class[_ <: Unit#T]]` is supposed to be. That doesn't work, there is no type member `T` in type `Unit`. What are you trying to express here? Should that just be `def liveIn: Option[T]`?

Comment: Don't consider my code as partial solution - it's just demonstration of main idea of the question. I want to have `liveIn` implementation for `Alien` that return `Some(classOf[ParallelUniverse])` and for `Human` that return `Some(classOf[Universe])`.

Comment: I think you need to put the question again from scratch, focusing on what you are trying to achieve. Why do you define `liveIn` both in `entity` and `Humanoid`, and why type `T` both in `Entity` and sub types of `Humanoid` (although here `T` is not a member of `Humanoid` itself)? If I understand your question correctly, it is roughly: "For a sub type of Humanoid, if I specify T, can I have filled in a definition of `liveIn` such that it yields an `Option` of `X <: Entity` such that `X.T == T`?

Comment: @0__ > Why do you define liveIn both in entity and Humanoid - Because Entity describe interface, Humanoid is implementation. > why type T both in Entity and sub types of Humanoid (although here T is not a member of Humanoid itself) - In Humanoid type should be generic. > If I understand your question correctly, it is roughly: "For a sub type of Humanoid, if I specify T, can I have filled in a definition of liveIn such that it yields an Option of X <: Entity such that X.T == T? - You absolutely right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems my problem solved in other way:

```
trait Entity[T <: Reality] {
  def liveIn: Option[Class[_ <: Entity[T]]]
}

abstract class World[T <: Reality] extends Entity[T] {
  def liveIn = None
}
class Universe extends World[Real.type]
class ParallelUniverse extends World[Unreal.type]

abstract class Humanoid[T <: Reality] extends Entity[T] {
  def liveIn = Some(classOf[World[T]])
}
class Human extends Humanoid[Real.type]
class Alien extends Humanoid[Unreal.type]

sealed trait Reality
case object Real extends Reality
case object Unreal extends Reality
```